# How to specify an attribute with a dash in a tag function?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to specify an attribute `data-*` in a `div` tag, how to I do it?
I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
tags$div(id='log', data-log='value')
```

Comment: In R you would need to use back-ticks to get a name that contained a dash or leading digits. I have no clue whether that succeeds with Shiny, but at least it would not choke the parser which is probably where you are getting stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the attribute would work!

```
tags$div(id='log',class='unique','data-log'='next')
```

Output (Html source):

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
        <div id="distPlot" class="shiny-plot-output" style="width: 100% ; height: 400px"></div>
        <div id="log" class="unique" data-log="next"></div>
      </div>
```